# Adding another div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, append, prepend

I'm looping through each relevant tag in an XML file and executing this code.

```
$('<div class="product_image"></div>').html('<a href="'+url+'"><img src='+urlZoomImage+' /></a>').appendTo('#content');
$('<div class="product_title"></div>').html('<a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a>').appendTo('#content');
```

I want to surround product_image and product_title with a div called product_box like this:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="product_box">
    <div class="product_image">My image code</div>
    <div class="product_title">My title code</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Only the content div is written in the HTML and it must remain like this (I can't write the product_box code in there as it is to be generated on each successful find).  How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are appending the elements to `#content` element, but you have a div element with class of `content`! typo?

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo, fixed OP now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily get lost in code, when you use jQuery for creating HTML elements. Try to save the seperate elements in variables and arrange them after initialising.
Like this:

```
var div_box = $('<div></div>').addClass('product_box');
var div_image = $('<div></div>').addClass('product_image').html('<a href="'+url+'"><img src='+urlZoomImage+' /></a>');
var div_title = $('<div></div>').addClass('product_title').html('<a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a>');
$('#content').append(div_box.append(div_image).append(div_title));
```

Comment: Yes, that's nice thanks. Just edited the last line to make it work:  $('#content').append(div_box.append(div_image).append(div_title));

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same syntax to create the `.product_box:` element, and then append the other content to *that* element, instead of to the `#content` element.

```
var product_box = $('<div />', {'class' : 'product_box'}).appendTo('#content');
$('<div class="product_image"></div>').html('<a href="'+url+'"><img src='+urlZoomImage+' /></a>').appendTo(product_box);
$('<div class="product_title"></div>').html('<a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a>').appendTo(product_box);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var box = $('<div class="product_box"></div>');
var product_image = $('<div class="product_image"></div>').html('<a href="'+url+'"><img src='+urlZoomImage+' /></a>');
var produc_title = $('<div class="product_title"></div>').html('<a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a>');

box.append(product_image,product_title).appendTo('.content');
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/append/)